# Excel VBA Delete Rows Based on Cell Value containing Part of a Text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete rows based on cell value that contains the words "upg" or "upgrade" inside the cell. when this word are there, it is not the only words inside the cell.

Here is part of my code, that not deletes anything:

```
Sub DeleteValues()


Dim i As Integer
Dim MFG_wb As Workbook
Dim Dep As Integer



Set MFG_wb = Workbooks.Open _
("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\MFG Daily\Fast Daily " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & ".xlsx", _
UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Activate

Dep = MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row


For i = Dep To 2 Step -1
    Cells(i, 2).Select
    If Not (Selection.Value = "& upg &" Or Selection.Value = "*& upgrade &*") Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i



End Sub
```

Here is the problem:

```
For i = Dep To 2 Step -1
    Cells(i, 2).Select
    If Not (Selection.Value = "& upg &" Or Selection.Value = "*& upgrade &*") Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use INSTR():

```
For i = Dep To 2 Step -1
     If Instr(MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Cells(i, 2).Value,"upg")>0 Or Instr(MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Cells(i, 2).Value,"upgrade") >0 Then
        MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Rows(i).Delete
     End If
Next i
```

Comment: Hey, that work well! Thanks!
Can you plese tell me how can I use more than two values?

Comment: I want to add to options "Upg" "UPGRADE" and "Upgrade" too.

Comment: No need to check for Upgrade if you're already checking for Upg, to check any case combinations you can make it uppercase UCase() first check for      Instr(UCase(MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Cells(i, 2).Value),"UPG")>0 or  UCase(MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Cells(i, 2).Value) like "UPG"